# Programming Error, New to C++

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I'm taking an intro class into C++ and we are using jgrasp. I'm doing a simple exercise right now which looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Testing 1, 2, 3\n";
    return 0;
}
```

though when I compile it and link it I get this error:

> ----jGRASP exec: g++ -c -fsyntax-only H:\COP2334\Excerises\Display 1.10
>
> g++.exe: warning: H:\COP2334\Excerises\Display 1.10: linker input file unused because linking not done
>
> ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Answer (score 2):

The option `-c` means "Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link."

So, of course, linking isn't performed.

Comment: Okay so I did just the compile function and now it reads "g++.exe: warning: H:\COP2334\Excerises\Display 1.10: linker input file unused because linking not done" how do I do the linking?

Comment: It appears the first time you did a "Semantic Check" and the second time a plain "Compile". You need to use "Compile and Link" on the "Build" menu (or Ctrl-B, or the "++" toolbar icon). If that is what you're doing, have you created a compiler environment, or maybe you were given one, that has the wrong commands in it? If not, use "Help" > "Report a Bug" to send a bug report.